# Vsphere REST API - how to specify fields in JSON response

Tags: api, vsphere

I am trying to return the names of VMs in a REST API call to Vcenter w/ the below request. I can get all fields by removing "name" from the request. Anyone know how to filter the response JSON object down to specific fields from Vcenter REST API?

https://fqdn/rest/vcenter/vm/name

Answer (score 2):

You're close, but you'll need to use the filter parameter to accomplish this.

Example:

```
GET https://{server}/rest/vcenter/vm&filter.names.1=vmname
```

More information about the filter options here: [VM List Method](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/423e512d-dda1-496f-9de3-851c28ca0814/0e3f6e0d-8d05-4f0c-887b-3d75d981bae5/VMware-vSphere-Automation-SDK-REST-6.7.0/docs/apidocs/operations/com/vmware/vcenter/vm.list-operation.html)